# How come this grammar is unambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar

> Equivalent unambiguous grammar:
>   \begin{align}
> S &\rightarrow ABA|AB|BA|A|B \\
> A &\rightarrow aA | a \\
> B &\rightarrow aB|b
> \end{align}

an unambiguous language has only one parse tree, but there are two parse trees for the grammar above:

$ABA > ABa > aBa > aba$

$ABA > aBA > abA > aba$

Comment: Those aren't parse trees. They are two derivations(?) corresponding to the same parse tree. Try drawing the actual tree and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the grammar, it's about the strings. If you see aaba there's only one way to parse it: aa is A, b is B, a is A, and the aaba = ABA is S.